# How can I enter null values on indexes where 2 arrays don't match?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeform

I'm retrieving answers from the Typeform API. I'll put these answers into a dataset where the questions are the column names.
All of this works, untill a question isn't answered.
This doesn't return a null value.
For example:

Questions : [A, B, C, D]

Answers: [a, c, d] -> Question B didn't receive an answer.

I expect an output of [a, null, c, d] for above example.

I tried multiple ways to implement this in my code, but I don't find the right answer.

```
  let surveys = formsAnswer.items.map(survey => {
    let i = 0
    let lam = survey.answers.map(ans => {
      let answ
      let rightID2 = schema.map(findID => {
        if (findID.id.toLowerCase() === req.body.id){
          let id = findID.columnID[i]
          i++
          return id
        }
      })
      switch (ans.type) {
        case 'boolean':
          answ = ans.boolean ? 'Yes' : 'No'
          break
        case 'choice':
          answ = ans.choice.label
          break
        case 'payment':
          answ = parseFloat(ans.payment.amount) * 100
          break
        case 'empty':
          answ = null
          break
        default:
          answ = ans[ans.type]
          break
      }
      return answ
    })
    return lam
  })
  return res.status(200).json(surveys)
})
```

In schema I have access to an array of all the question IDs from 1 form.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**
Example output of a survey with 10 questions.

```
   [
       [["ZoW7FL2pVKvR","gfds"],
        ["amx5Q2JU4Qa7","Car 1"],
        ["jlqW0xFRGXdm","No"],
        ["FhfIURjvE8nN","dfs@hotmail.com"], 
        ["vVTYmlvc1YIy",0] 
        ["DqX2Dy0cvmMy","fezfze"]],

       [["ZoW7FL2pVKvR", "Ruben"],
        ["ihNcWeYgZHPb","Male"],
        ["amx5Q2JU4Qa7","Car 2"],
        ["jlqW0xFRGXdm", "Yes"],
        ["FhfIURjvE8nN","ruben@gmail.com"],
        ["vVTYmlvc1YIy", 2],
        ["b8y0pDw3gYpn","No"],
        ["beeg0rtb7Mai","1995-02-10T00:00:00Z"],
        ["Knox8dyeM4Ak",10]]
  ]
```

This is the array of the all the questionIDs from 1 survey

```
"columnID": [
      "ZoW7FL2pVKvR",
      "ihNcWeYgZHPb",
      "amx5Q2JU4Qa7",
      "jlqW0xFRGXdm",
      "FhfIURjvE8nN",
      "vVTYmlvc1YIy",
      "b8y0pDw3gYpn",
      "beeg0rtb7Mai",
      "Knox8dyeM4Ak",
      "DqX2Dy0cvmMy"
    ]
```

Comment: I don't get the problem? Don't use null but just use 0? your array will be [a,0,c,d]

Comment: The problem isn't about 0 or null. It's if I have an array of questions [A, B, C, D], and the person only answered questions [A, C, D]. Then I retrieve the answer C on the index of question B. In my variable lam I map over these retrieved answers, but I need to find a way where I can check the id of the answered question, and match this with the index of the questions.

Comment: Before the user chooses an answer, initialise an Array of null items matching the length of how many questions there are. `[null, null, null, null]` Then upon interaction from the user you can take the questions answer and plop it into place of the initial array. if the user does not answer one atleast now you will have a null in-place of that question.

Comment: Well, because you push NULL, the place will be empty, however if u push 0, it will take the place of B. So [A,B,C,D] and [A,0,C,D], C has same index. So yeah, the problem is about 0 or null

Comment: The output seems flawed in order to validate specific questions. you could validate specific *sections* based on length of answers against length of array in output but in order to match answers up to questions you'd need some sort of key/id Link

Comment: @FrancisLeigh, thanks for the repo. I've added the question id's with the answers for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you, why the answer is not in your list, because I don't understand your code, but I might be able to help you get the array, you want.

Assume you have an array with the ids of all questions called questionIds

```
const allAnswers = questionIds.map(questionId => getAnswerForQuestionByQuestionId(questionId, answers)

function getAnswerForQuestionByQuestionId(questionId, answers) {
  for(const answer of answers) {
    if (answer[0] === questionId) {
      return answer[1]
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

This will return the array you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the whole anser array and build new arrays with prefilled `null` values and assign each given value to the wanted index.

```js
var answers = [[["ZoW7FL2pVKvR", "gfds"], ["amx5Q2JU4Qa7", "Car 1"], ["jlqW0xFRGXdm", "No"], ["FhfIURjvE8nN", "dfs@hotmail.com"], ["vVTYmlvc1YIy", 0], ["DqX2Dy0cvmMy", "fezfze"]], [["ZoW7FL2pVKvR", "Ruben"], ["ihNcWeYgZHPb", "Male"], ["amx5Q2JU4Qa7", "Car 2"], ["jlqW0xFRGXdm", "Yes"], ["FhfIURjvE8nN", "ruben@gmail.com"], ["vVTYmlvc1YIy", 2], ["b8y0pDw3gYpn", "No"], ["beeg0rtb7Mai", "1995-02-10T00:00:00Z"], ["Knox8dyeM4Ak", 10]]],
    questions = ["ZoW7FL2pVKvR", "ihNcWeYgZHPb", "amx5Q2JU4Qa7", "jlqW0xFRGXdm", "FhfIURjvE8nN", "vVTYmlvc1YIy", "b8y0pDw3gYpn", "beeg0rtb7Mai", "Knox8dyeM4Ak", "DqX2Dy0cvmMy"],
    indices = Object.assign(...questions.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: i }))),
    remapped = answers.map(a => a.reduce((r, b) => {
        r[indices[b[0]]] = b;
        return r;
    }, Array.from({ length: questions.length }).fill(null)));

console.log(remapped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This also worked, thanks! But bit more complex then the accepted answer.